# Angular typeError: Observable.combineLatest is not a function

Tags: angular

```
 TypeError: rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Observable.combineLatest is not a function.
```

Angular version `6.2.2`, rxjs: `6.3.2`.

My code is given below:

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.combineLatest([
    this.route.paramMap,
    this.route.queryParamMap
  ])
  .switchMap(combined => {
    let id = combined[0].get('id');
    let page = combined[1].get('page');

    return this.service.getAll();
  })
  .subscribe(followers => this.followers = followers);  
}
```

Trying get the list of `followers` using `http` request path given in some other file.

Answer (score 2):

combineLatest is not part of the observable object. just use `combineLatest`. Also, wrap the `switchMap` around `pipe` function

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let observerObj = combineLatest([
     this.route.paramMap,
     this.route.queryParamMap
 ]);
observerObj
  .pipe(
    switchMap(combined => {
        let id = combined[0].get('id');
        let page = combined[1].get('page');
        return this.service.getAll();
    })
  ) 
  .subscribe(followers => this.followers = followers);
```

Comment: Nice One! Thanks. Thumbs up!